# firefox and watir wouldn't work on windows due to a singularize method not found, what's wrong?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

I just installed a fresh copy of ruby 1.8.7 on Windows XP SP3 32bits.
Install watir.

I used the wikipedia example :

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'watir/ie' 
Watir::Browser.default = 'ie'

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

so far so good, works as expected

now

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'watir/ie' 
Watir::Browser.default = 'firefox'

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto("http://www.google.com")
```

throws an ugly

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>ruby watir2.rb
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:89:in `
klass': undefined method `singularize' for "Buttons":String (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.6.5/lib/firewatir/ele
ment_collections.rb:185
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
`require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.6.5/lib/firewatir.rb:
29
        from (eval):1:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/brows
er.rb:65:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/brows
er.rb:89:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/brows
er.rb:65:in `new'
        from watir2.rb:7
```

It should be mentioned that i have followed the procedure documented there http://watir.com/installation/#win
besides, I think it's unrelated but I do have the jssh firefox plugin installed as expected.

**what's does this undefined method `singularize' stands for ?**

below is some environment info

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (3.0.0)
builder (2.1.2)
commonwatir (1.6.5)
firewatir (1.6.5)
hoe (2.6.1)
json_pure (1.4.6)
nokogiri (1.4.3.1 x86-mingw32)
rake (0.8.7)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir (1.6.5)
win32-api (1.4.6 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.6.2)
windows-api (0.4.0)
windows-pr (1.0.9)
xml-simple (1.0.12)

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>
```

Comment: just in case someone suggests it, i tried to downgrade firewatir from 1.6.5 to 1.6.2, but it just didn't work (i guess it was worth trying anyway :p

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Ru
byGem version error: firewatir(1.6.2 not = 1.6.5) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
[bla bla bla...]

Comment: i tried that too.

but it fails while trying to gem install watir :
ERROR:    Error installing watir :
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7

so basically latest watir can't work with 1.8.6 
maybe with an older watir then...

Comment: tried with watir 1.6.2, 1.5.6, 1.5.5 ==> each demanded ruby 1.8.7
at last watir 1.5.4 installs
but now the script no longer work even with ie :(
uninitialized constant Watir::Exception
maybe it's related to the fact that the Watir::IE became Watir::Browser at some point in the past, i feel tired :(

Comment: if you do a require 'active_support' can you do "".singularize?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir) is not maintained by Watir team, so it is probably not up to date. Please use only examples from [watir.com](http://watir.com/).

I took a look at Wikipedia article and I could not find `require 'watir/ie'` anywhere, please use just `require 'watir'`.

I have installed Ruby [1.8.7-p302](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/72085/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p302.exe) from [rubyinstaller.org/downloads](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) on a fully patched XP SP3 32 bit machine, and installed Watir with `gem install watir`.

I have installed [Firefox 3.6.8](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html) and [Windows plugin for Firefox 3.6](http://wiki.openqa.org/download/attachments/13893658/jssh-3.6-WINNT.xpi) from [watir.com/installation](http://watir.com/installation/).

I have executed code from [watir.com/examples](http://watir.com/examples/)

```
require "rubygems"    
require "watir"
Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
Watir::Browser.new
```

but I got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `demodulize' for "FireWatir::Pre":String
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:89:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.6.5/lib/firewatir/elements/non_control_elements.rb:2
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.6.5/lib/firewatir.rb:15
        from (eval):1:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:65:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:89:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.5/lib/watir/browser.rb:65:in `new'
        from (irb):4
```

Really strange. That used to work.

If you want to drive Firefox with Watir, I would suggest [watir-webdriver](http://zeljkofilipin.com/2010/01/12/watir-on-webdriver/) gem until this is fixed.

Comment: mmm interesting
i tried with

require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
browser.goto("http://www.google.com")

and also

require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:ie)
browser.goto("http://www.google.com")

in both cases, i get 
watir3.rb:3: uninitialized constant Watir (NameError)

wtf ???

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works at my machine. Really strange. Uninstall Ruby and try installing it with only watir-webdriver. Not sure if that would help, but you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `require 'active_support'` somewhere in your code. Looks like the guys didn't specify active_support as dependency. *add rant here*

Comment: didnt work. i tried right after require 'rubygems', in the failiing firewatir file, i try inside the module, outsite, reverse order or 'rubygems' and 'active_support'
none of that worked :'(

Comment: Error report would be useful. And `rubygems` needs to be first.

Comment: basically the reported error is just the same: undefined method `singularize'

Answer (score 0):

works for me with 1.8.6 (mingw) + active_support 2.3.8 + watir (though I get a "please install jssh" message when I use it with firefox).

My first hunch is that you have some conflict among gems, and rubygems "always chooses the first"

You could install the gem_conflict_checker gem (which includes a rubygems plugin to test for the same).  Install it then install the watir gem and it should tell you of existing conflict.

In answer to your original question, here's singularize: http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/11/stringsingularize.html

-r

Comment: how come i have a gem conflict ? i used a fersh windows totally clean (never saw any ruby binary before), installed a fresh 1.8.7 with the one click installer (the lastest one as of yesterday or so), then issued a gem update (nothing to update), then gem install watir.
and i can seriously get a gem conflict with that? (sorry if the question feels bump...)

will try gem_conflict_checker asap